# How to Swap data from one column to another in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to figure out how I can swap data bewteen two columns.  The data in col b should be in col d.

EX:

```
col a    col b    col c   col d
  1982     38      M        Late   
  1983     37      F        Early  
  1984    Late     M        36
```

How would I swap the values in row 3, for only those two columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df=df[['col a', 'col d', 'col c', 'col b']]`?

Comment: Yeah, but I need only the values in 1984 col b and col d to be swapped with each other.  I'm trying to find a way to make only that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.where(Condition, outcomeIfConditionTrue, outcomeIfConditionFalse)`. Combine this with python's interchange denoted by `a,b=b,a`

```
    df['col b'],df['col d']=np.where(df['col a'].eq(1984),df['col d'],df['col b']),np.where(df['col a'].eq(1984),df['col b'],df['col d'])
print(df)



 col a  col b  col c col d
0  1982   38    M   Late
1  1983   37    F  Early
2  1984   36    M   Late
```

Comment: That worked! Amazingly well.  Can you explain the .eq part to me, please?